# Java Swing JComboBox uneditable

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox

I've come across a very weird problem. I had a JPanel which contains JTextFields and JComboBoxes. I can change the JComboBox's when the JPanel loads but as soon as I touch or edit one of the JTextFields it doesn't let me change any of the combobox's...

Here is an MCVE that works. You can use it straight away and you'll see the error.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class Main extends JFrame{

    private static JTextField s;
    private static JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private static JPanel config;
    private static JComboBox<Object> dns;
    private static JComboBox<Object> dnsmm;
    private static JButton save;
    private static String interval;
    private static String dnsen;
    private static String dnsm;
    private static JPanel server;
    static JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Main frame = new Main();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    }


    public Main() throws IOException {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 655, 470);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1, 1));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        contentPane.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setResizable(false);

        server = new JPanel();
        server.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        ServerPanel();
    }

    public static void ServerPanel() throws IOException{ 

        tabbedPane.addTab("Manage Server", server);
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("config.dedserver");
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(in);
        in.close();
        String saveInt = p.getProperty("saveInterval");
        String dnse = p.getProperty("enableDns");
        String dnsmo = p.getProperty("serverMode");

        config = new JPanel();
        server.add(config, BorderLayout.CENTER);    
        config.setLayout(new BoxLayout(config, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));


        //saveint
        Panel panel_6 = new Panel();
        config.add(panel_6);
        JLabel sl = new JLabel("Save Interval (milliseconds):    ");
        panel_6.add(sl);
        s = new JTextField(saveInt);
        panel_6.add(s);
        s.setColumns(10);

        //dnsenabled
        Panel panel_9 = new Panel();
        config.add(panel_9);
        JLabel dnsl = new JLabel("DNS Enabled:    ");
        panel_9.add(dnsl);
        String[] dnsS = { "true", "false" };
        dns = new JComboBox<Object>(dnsS);
        dns.setSelectedItem(dnse);
        dns.addActionListener(dns);
        panel_9.add(dns);


        //dnsmode
        Panel panel_10 = new Panel();
        config.add(panel_10);
        JLabel dnsml = new JLabel("DNS Server Mode:    ");
        panel_10.add(dnsml);
        String[] dnsm = { "local", "remote" };
        dnsmm = new JComboBox<Object>(dnsm);
        dnsmm.setSelectedItem(dnsmo);
        dnsmm.addActionListener(dnsmm);
        panel_10.add(dnsmm);

        JPanel panel_7= new JPanel();
        config.add(panel_7);
        save = new JButton("Save");
        panel_7.add(save);
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                errorCheck();       
            }
        });
    }

    public static void errorCheck(){
        interval = s.getText();
        dnsen = (String) dns.getSelectedItem();
        dnsm = (String) dnsmm.getSelectedItem();

        interval = checkValues(interval, "60000", "save interval");
        saveValues();
    }

    public static String checkValues(String value, String def, String name){
        String val;
        try{
            Long.parseLong(value);
            val = ""+value+"";
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not enter a valid number for the "+ name + " field! It has been set to the default.");
            val = def;
        }
        return val;
    }

    public static void saveValues(){
        try {
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.setProperty("saveInterval", interval);
                props.setProperty("serverMode", dnsm);
                props.setProperty("enableDns", dnsen);

                File f = new File("config.dedserver");
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
                props.store(out, "");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved Config Values!");

            }
            catch (Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
}
```

For it to work you will also need to make a config.dedserver in the root of the project and add the following stuff into it:

```
#
#Thu Jul 09 08:29:33 BST 2015
saveMethod=h2
startingGems=9999999999
enableDns=true
startingGold=9999999999
startingDarkElixir=9999999999
startingElixir=9999999999
serverMode=remote
saveInterval=30000
maxNameChanges=100
```

For the entire ServerPanel.java code it is here: http://pastebin.com/tvBENHQa

I'm not sure why this isn't working. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewThompson I posted an MCVE but I also posted the full code if someone wants to reference it as well :/

Comment: This `dnsmm.addActionListener(dnsmm);` doesn't make sense. Why add the combo box itself as an ActionListener to itself?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ok I've posted one now.

Comment: I've the code it seems to work okay for me.  Things that do stand out though are the over use of `static`, adding the combobox as `ActionListener` to itself and you're not managing your streams (closing them when you're finished)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Panel` with `JPanel` you are mixing awt Component with Swing that's causing the issue.

> Swing components are "lightweight" (rendered by Java) while AWT
>   components are "heavyweight" (implemented as components in the host
>   platform) - this means you will have problems if you put AWT
>   components inside Swing components (the other way round is fine)

```
//saveint
   // Panel panel_6 = new Panel();// replace as below
    JPanel panel_6 = new JPanel();

//dnsenabled
   // Panel panel_9 = new Panel();
   JPanel panel_9 = new JPanel();

//dnsmode
    //Panel panel_10 = new Panel();
    JPanel panel_10 = new JPanel();
```

And also remove action listener as said by @KDM

Answer (score 0):

Though the `JComboBox` implements `ActionListener` interface it is for its own internal use. You shouldn't be adding itself to `addActionListener`. Remove it and see whether it helps.

Here is the updated code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class Main extends JFrame{

    private static JTextField s;
    private static JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private static JPanel config;
    private static JComboBox<Object> dns;
    private static JComboBox<Object> dnsmm;
    private static JButton save;
    private static String interval;
    private static String dnsen;
    private static String dnsm;
    private static JPanel server;
    static JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Main frame = new Main();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    }


    public Main() throws IOException {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 655, 470);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1, 1));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        contentPane.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setResizable(false);

        server = new JPanel();
        server.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        ServerPanel();
    }

    public static void ServerPanel() throws IOException{ 

        tabbedPane.addTab("Manage Server", server);
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("config.dedserver");
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(in);
        in.close();
        String saveInt = p.getProperty("saveInterval");
        String dnse = p.getProperty("enableDns");
        String dnsmo = p.getProperty("serverMode");

        config = new JPanel();
        server.add(config, BorderLayout.CENTER);    
        config.setLayout(new BoxLayout(config, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));


        //saveint
        Panel panel_6 = new Panel();
        config.add(panel_6);
        JLabel sl = new JLabel("Save Interval (milliseconds):    ");
        panel_6.add(sl);
        s = new JTextField(saveInt);
        panel_6.add(s);
        s.setColumns(10);

        //dnsenabled
        Panel panel_9 = new Panel();
        config.add(panel_9);
        JLabel dnsl = new JLabel("DNS Enabled:    ");
        panel_9.add(dnsl);
        String[] dnsS = { "true", "false" };
        dns = new JComboBox<Object>(dnsS);
        dns.setSelectedItem(dnse);
        panel_9.add(dns);


        //dnsmode
        Panel panel_10 = new Panel();
        config.add(panel_10);
        JLabel dnsml = new JLabel("DNS Server Mode:    ");
        panel_10.add(dnsml);
        String[] dnsm = { "local", "remote" };
        dnsmm = new JComboBox<Object>(dnsm);
        dnsmm.setSelectedItem(dnsmo);
        panel_10.add(dnsmm);

        JPanel panel_7= new JPanel();
        config.add(panel_7);
        save = new JButton("Save");
        panel_7.add(save);
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                errorCheck();       
            }
        });
    }

    public static void errorCheck(){
        interval = s.getText();
        dnsen = (String) dns.getSelectedItem();
        dnsm = (String) dnsmm.getSelectedItem();

        interval = checkValues(interval, "60000", "save interval");
        saveValues();
    }

    public static String checkValues(String value, String def, String name){
        String val;
        try{
            Long.parseLong(value);
            val = ""+value+"";
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not enter a valid number for the "+ name + " field! It has been set to the default.");
            val = def;
        }
        return val;
    }

    public static void saveValues(){
        try {
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.setProperty("saveInterval", interval);
                props.setProperty("serverMode", dnsm);
                props.setProperty("enableDns", dnsen);

                File f = new File("config.dedserver");
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
                props.store(out, "");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved Config Values!");

            }
            catch (Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer what should I do to fix this then?

Comment: @ShivamPaw Before we can know that, we'd need to have a runnable example

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hi, posted one now. Sorry about that.

Comment: I am sure that this is the issue with the combo box not selecting - I could reproduce it. Looking at the paste bin, why were you using `static` variables for the widgets in the panel? Shouldn't they be member variables of the panel class?

Comment: @KDM so how do I fix it??

Comment: I don't know what you tried. From the code you posted removing the `addActionListener()` calls on the combo box the form works properly.

Comment: @KDM I removed that from the MCVE code but still doesn't work.. can you post the code you used to get it to work pls